# c# parse and replace content in string

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-parsing

This is my first attempt to use regular expression.

What I want to archieve is to convert this string:

```
" <Control1 x:Uid="1"  />

  <Control2 x:Uid="2"  /> "
```

to

```
" <Control1 {1}  />

  <Control2 {2}  /> "
```

Basically, convert **x:Uid="n"** to **{n}**, where **n** represents an integer.

What I thought it would work (of course it doesn't) is like this:

```
  string input = " <Control1 x:Uid="1"  />
                   <Control2 x:Uid="2"  /> ";

  string pattern = "\b[x:Uid=\"[\d]\"]\w+";
  string replacement = "{}";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Or

```
  Regex.Replace(input, pattern, delegate(Match match)
  {
       // do something here
       return result
  });
```

I'm struggling to define the pattern and replacement string. I'm not sure if I'm in the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: You may ommit the \b and \w as well as the braces around x:Uid. Try this instead: x:Uid=\"(\d)\" in order to retrieve the integers and then set replacement to {$1}

Comment: Just to make sure: `Uid`s can only be exactly one digit long? Because `\d` matches exactly one digit.

Comment: So \d+ should be used if it's one or more digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which you don't want here. Instead you want to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
string pattern = @"\bx:Uid=""(\d)""";
string replacement = "{$1}";
```

Note the use of a verbatim string to make sure the `\b` is interpreted as a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) instead of a backspace character.

Comment: You´ll have to escape the " within your regex by using \"

Comment: @HimBromBeere - he already escaped it, by using `""` (in a verbatim string, preceded by that `@`)

Comment: Shouldn't `\d+` be used instead? Even thought the author did not state so I have a feeling it might be more than one digit in the real implementation :)

Comment: @flindeberg: Thus my comment/question above.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I totally missed that :)